# Updating old customization code using deprecated lexical-let

Tags: let-binding, lexical-binding

Old code

```
(lexical-let ((beg -1)
      (end -1)
      (prev-mid -1))

(defun forward-binary ()
   (interactive)
   (if (/= prev-mid (point))
       (setq beg -1 end -1)
     (setq beg prev-mid))
   (if (< end 0) (setq beg (point)
               end (line-end-position)))
   (setq prev-mid (/ (+ beg end ) 2))
   (goto-char prev-mid))


(defun backward-binary ()
   (interactive)
   (if (/= prev-mid (point)) 
       (setq beg -1 end -1)
     (setq end prev-mid))
   (if (< beg 0) (setq beg (line-beginning-position)
               end (point)))
   (setq prev-mid (/ (+ beg end) 2))
   (goto-char prev-mid))

) ;; closes lexical-let

(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-<left>")  'backward-binary)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-<right>")  'forward-binary)
```

This doesn't work anymore.
What can I replace lexical-let with?
I tried plain `let` but that caused other errors (`prev-mid` undefined)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Did you turn on variable `lexical-binding` in the current context (file)? See the doc for that option and for lexical bindings generally.

Comment: Do I need lexical-binding to begin with @Drew